# jquery toggleClass on nav is not seeing child link in a div

Tags: jquery, events, hyperlink, click

I'm revealing a simple nav with display: block; and display: none. I'm using jQuery to toggleClass. That's working fine. But my click isn't getting to the link inside the divs within the nav.

How to I force it? (this is Meteor syntax, but that shouldn't matter, right?)

```
'tap .navbuttons': function(e) {
  $('nav').toggleClass('shownav');
}
```

Here's a sample div from the nav area:

```
<div id="search" class="navbuttons"><a href="{{pathFor 'startPage'}}">Search</a></div>
```

I'm expecting it to see the click on the link, route to that page (pathFor 'startPage' is from iron-router) and display: none; on the nav. I shouldn't have to put jQuery for the click in that function, should I? Won't the link simply do it's job?

I figure I've got a bubbling or propagation issue, but I haven't been able to work it out.

My classes are working fine, no need to show the CSS.

Comment: What happens when you click on the link inside the nav? Please clarify the issue. (Thumbs up for using Meteor. It's awesome, no? :)

Comment: The nav goes away. I remain on the currently visible page. It's as if the link isn't getting triggered. (Yep, getting more done with Meteor than with any other frameworks I've tried. Really liking it.)

Comment: That's strange. Usually issues with propagation only happen when going up the tree, not down. What happens if that class does NOT hide the navigation?

Comment: Then it switches to the page I want, but leaves the nav covering half my screen.

Comment: It must be some weird Meteor behavior bc I've never seen an issue in pure JS of hiding the parent preventing the click from reaching the child. If anything it would change pages and not hide the navigation.

Comment: I've got it working by writing functions for each link, but that seems stupid. I also had to add a setTimeout before calling the Router.

Comment: I would post this on the meteor google group, but they tend to ignore pesky issues like this there.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't help out more. I'm still new to Meteor. Good luck!

Comment: When your click event bubbles up the tree and causes the nav to close, if you have any `e.preventDefault()` in any of the close-nav functions it could be interfering with your link routing. You could test this by wrapping the entire close-nav function in an if statement, like `if (!e.target.is('a')) { //close the nav }`